# Where to set BluetoothGatt connection priority

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

After successfully connecting to a Bluetooth device and discovering services, inside `onServicesDiscovered` callback, I do the following in the same sequence:

- `bluetoothGatt?.requestMtu(244)`
- `bluetoothGatt?.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH)`
- Enable a characteristic indication/notification.

After trying like this (and inside several other callbacks as well), I fail to successfully set the connection priority **unless I put a delay of atleast 5 seconds** before I call `requestConnectionPriority()` method. As soon as I put the delay, the priority starts to work as expected.

I wanted to know that if there is a better way or an actual callback from where I am supposed to call this method.

Comment: you can set connection priority in onConnectionStateChange function

Comment: I did but it seems like doesn't do anything. The latency to receive data packets only lowers of I call it this way